# Why does this thruster have a sideways component?

Tags: sdformat, gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using the thruster plugin for ignition gazebo and publish a constant thrust to it of 0.1.
The joint is offset from the center by -0.1 in the y-direction and rotated by -1.57079632679 around the y-axis. I would expect the model to move to the right and rotate a bit in the x-y-plane but on top of that it also tilts downward as you can see in the [gif](https://imgur.com/a/3IQ3VYg). Do you have any idea why this is happening ? Here is the sdf file, the thruster that is moving in the gif is called thruster_b:

```
<sdf version='1.8'>
<world name='auv'>
<scene>
  <sky>
    <clouds>
      <speed>12</speed>
    </clouds>
  </sky>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
  <fog>
    <color>0.05 0.2 0.2 1.0</color>
    <type>linear</type>
    <density>0.1</density>
    <start>1</start>
    <end>4</end>
  </fog>
  <ambient>0 1 1 1</ambient>
  <background>0 0.7 0.8 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>
<physics name='1ms' type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
</physics>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics' filename='ignition-gazebo-physics-system'/>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands' filename='ignition-gazebo-user-commands-system'/>
<plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster' filename='ignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system'/>
<plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors" filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system">
  <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
</plugin>
<plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu" filename="libignition-gazebo-imu-system.so"/>
<plugin name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Altimeter" filename="libignition-gazebo-altimeter-system.so"/>

<gui>
  <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>3D View</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
    </ignition-gui>

    <engine>ogre2</engine>
    <scene>scene</scene>
    <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
    <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
    <camera_pose>0 1 1 0 0.5 -1.57079632679</camera_pose>
  </plugin>

  <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>World control</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">72</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">121</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

      <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
      <anchors target="3D View">
        <line own="left" target="left"/>
        <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
      </anchors>
    </ignition-gui>

    <play_pause>true</play_pause>
    <step>true</step>
    <start_paused>true</start_paused>
  </plugin>

  <!-- World statistics -->
  <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
    <ignition-gui>
      <title>World stats</title>
      <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
      <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
      <property type="double" key="height">110</property>
      <property type="double" key="width">290</property>
      <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

      <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
      <anchors target="3D View">
        <line own="right" target="right"/>
        <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
      </anchors>
    </ignition-gui>

    <sim_time>true</sim_time>
    <real_time>true</real_time>
    <real_time_factor>true</real_time_factor>
    <iterations>true</iterations>
  </plugin>
</gui>

<light name='sun' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
  <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>1 1 1 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.5 0.5 0.5 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.90000000000000002</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
  <spot>
    <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
    <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
    <falloff>0</falloff>
  </spot>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
</light>
<gravity>0 0 0</gravity>
<magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
<atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>

<model name="ground_plane">
  <static>true</static>
  <link name="link">
    <pose>0 0 -10.0 0 0 0</pose>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>20 20 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>20 20 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<model name='auv'>
  <link name='base_link'>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.1</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.1</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.1</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <collision name='base_link_buoyancy'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
        <bounce/>
        <contact/>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name='base_link_main_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.01 0.01 0.01</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <!-- Thruster -->
  <link name='thruster_l'>
    <pose>0.1 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_l_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_l_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_l</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_l_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>

  <link name='thruster_r'>
    <pose>-0.1 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_r_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_r_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_r</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_r_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>

  <link name='thruster_f'>
    <pose>0 0.1 0 0 -1.57079632679 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_f_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_f</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_f_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>

  <link name='thruster_b'>
    <pose>0 -0.1 0 0 -1.57079632679 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_b_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_b_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_b</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_b_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>

  <link name='thruster_u'>
    <pose>0 0 0.1 1.57079632679 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_u_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_u_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_u</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_u_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>

  <link name='thruster_d'>
    <pose>0 0 -0.1 1.57079632679 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.1</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name='thruster_d_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/thruster_simple.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <visual name='arrow_f_visual'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>../models/arrow.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </link>

  <joint name='thruster_d_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>thruster_d</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-1000000000000</lower>
        <upper>1000000000000</upper>
        <effort>-1</effort>
        <velocity>-1</velocity>
      </limit>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Thruster' filename='ignition-gazebo-thruster-system'>
    <namespace>auv</namespace>
    <joint_name>thruster_d_joint</joint_name>
    <thrust_coefficient>0.01</thrust_coefficient>
    <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
    <propeller_diameter>0.1</propeller_diameter>
  </plugin>
</model>
</world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28114/why-does-this-thruster-have-a-sideways-component-?/) by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I resolved the issue by setting <velocity_control> to 1 in the sdf file at the thruster plugin part.
I looked it up in the thruster plugin source code: If this isn't set to 1 a torque is added that lead to the weird behaviour for me.

---

Originally posted by [florian.pix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81881/florian.pix/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0